# Total Number of records required in paged .NET datagrid control

Tags: c#, asp.net, .net, datagrid, custompaging

I am using a data grid and has bound a data source with it.

I am trying to get the total number of records in the grid in overriden InitializePager method from pagedDataSource DataSourceCount.

I thought DataSourceCount returns number of records from SelectCountMethod of ObjectDataSource, but DataSourceCount is giving me the page size and not the total number of records, whereas when I debug and see in SelectCountMethod it is returning correct number of total Records.

I am not sure how to get the data from SelectCountMethod  in DataGrid.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The DataSource has a **Selected** Event which is fired when the Select and the SelectCount method are executed. Even if its a bit ugly it is a way to get the count:

```
protected void MyDataSource_Selected(object sender, ObjectDataSourceStatusEventArgs e)
{
    var count = e.ReturnValue as int?;
    if (count.HasValue)
        litResults.Text = string.Format("Total results found {0}", count);
}
```

My Count method of the ObjectDataSource returns an int, so of the ReturnValue of the Selected EventArgs is an int, its the count.

Hope this helps you.